# "incompatible parameter types in method reference" when trying to method reference Class method

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock a static method `render` of the `TemplateRendererUtil` class to return `null` when testing. Not sure if this is the right approach, the method I'm trying to test calls this class, but I just want it to essentially skip this.

Getting a compilation error here:

```java
try (MockedStatic<TemplateRendererUtil> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(TemplateRendererUtil.class)){
    // java: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in method reference
    mockedStatic.when(TemplateRendererUtil::render).thenReturn(null);
}
```

Class being referenced:

```java
    public class TemplateRendererUtil {
        private static final ResponseTemplateRenderer RENDERER = ResponseTemplateRenderer.getInstance();
    
        private TemplateRendererUtil() {
        }
    
        public static void render(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, String templateFile, Map<String, Object> params) throws TemplateRendererUtilException {
            try {
                RENDERER.render(req, resp, templateFile, params);
            } catch (ResponseTemplateRendererException var5) {
                throw new TemplateRendererUtilException(var5);
            }
        }
    }
```

Stack trace of at `Mockito.mockStatic`:

```
    java.lang.InternalError: class redefinition failed: invalid class

    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:167)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:280)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.mockClassStatic(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:225)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClassStatic(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:63)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.createStaticMock(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:560)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createStaticMock(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:83)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createStaticMock(MockUtil.java:147)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mockStatic(MockitoCore.java:142)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mockStatic(Mockito.java:2181)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mockStatic(Mockito.java:2118)
    ...
```

Comment: you need to supply mocked parameters to render() method

Answer (score 0):

As I see, render method is not returning anything so you can do like this

```
try (MockedStatic<TemplateRendererUtil> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(TemplateRendererUtil.class)){
                    
 doNothing().when(TemplateRendererUtil.render(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyMap()));

}
```

Comment: I get "java: 'void' type not allowed here" at "render"

Comment: This does not compile as `render` method does not return anything (is `void`). `thenAnswer` method should be used - see my answer above.

Comment: @Jonasz doNothing().when() will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two problems with your code.

First is the fact that you did not provide the code for the method `TemplateRendererUtil.render()` (without arguments) and you're using such a method's reference as a parameter passed to `when()`. You're not referencing the method with 4 arguments that you've shown in your test code.

The second problem is the fact that you're trying to return `null` from a method that does not return anything (`void` type).

The correct code would be:

```java
try (MockedStatic<TemplateRendererUtil> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(TemplateRendererUtil.class)) {
    mockedStatic.when(() -> TemplateRendererUtil.render(any(), any(), anyString(), anyMap()))
                .thenAnswer(inv -> null);
    // rest of the test
}
```

Instead of `any...` matchers you could use more appropriate ones if needed.

---

I've reproduced the problem and tested the solution - you can find it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/blob/73302606/src/test/java/io/github/jonarzz/MockStaticTest.java). The test passes. The mocked method was simplified to use `int` and `long`, but the mechanism stays the same.

Comment: I'm getting a compiler error "try (MockedStatic<TemplateRendererUtil> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(TemplateRendererUtil.class))" at mockStatic "java.lang.InternalError: class redefinition failed: invalid class"

Comment: Thank you for your first answer, it makes sense with what I am trying to do.

Comment: Could you provide the complete stack trace of the error you're getting? You can edit the original question and attach it there.

Comment: Added stack trace.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is verification if the classes are compiled with compatible JDK versions and if the class is present on test classpath, but if it's the same module of the project built using Maven or other tool, it should be OK. You could also try and run the test in a different way, e.g. if you're running using IntelliJ, try running `mvn clean test` command from the terminal.

Comment: Could it be because the class is from an "sdk.template", even if I just try and call the "TemplateRendererUtil.render(request,response,anyString(),anyMap())" in my test I get "Unhandled exception". I am importing the class in my tests.

Comment: This could also be caused by `RENDERER.render` throwing a NullPointerException as Mockito passes `null` values where matchers are used. You could try and replace the argument matchers (`any()`, `anyString()` etc.) with actual objects. You could also try and mock `ResponseTemplateRenderer.getInstance()` method so that it returns a mocked value. Also if you have access to the `TemplateRendererUtil` class code, you could add another catch to handle all exceptions and log them there, because an exception thrown from there could be causing the error when mocking.

Comment: The "Unhandled exception" issue is because I wasn't catching exceptions. No tests run when I use  mvn clean test.